# SlickGrid - Retrieving Data from and saving back to MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, slickgrid

I have looked at the following post regarding retrieving and saving data to and from MySQL with SlickGrid and PHP:

[How to use jQuery SlickGrid with PHP / MySQL (load server data and save changes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776600/how-to-use-jquery-slickgrid-with-php-mysql-load-server-data-and-save-changes)

Unfortunately I am very new to both PHP and SlickGrid. I am very unsure about where to put the PHP code to enable access to the MySQL. As cannot put it into the index.html file containing my SlickGrid implementation as it will not get parsed by my server with it not being a .php file.

Answer (score 0):

choose some web application framework.
I use `codeigniter`. It follows mvc architecture. In views have your html code of `slickgrid` , in controller direct the pages, have `ajax` controls and in the model retrieve from `sql` through sql queries