# Slickgrid save all data at once

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

I am trying to save all the data in a slickgrid at once rather than one at a time, my plan was to use 
[Saving changes in SlickGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228066/saving-changes-in-slickgrid)
so my code is :

```
<script language='javascript' type="text/javascript">
    function saveQuote() {

    $("input[name='mydata']").val(jQuery.parseJSON(grid.getData()));
  }
</script>
```

with my data being a textbox ... (so I can debug and see what is happening)
My Grid is empty to begin with and the user adding data(which has calculations etc)
however when I press my save button and call my saveQuote no data is being presented, any one know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was with:

```
   $("input[name='mydata']").val(jQuery.parseJSON(grid.getData()));
```

so I replaced it with

```
$("input[name='mydata']").val(JSON.stringify(grid.getData()));
```

full code is now:

```
<script language='javascript' type="text/javascript">
   function saveQuote() {
    $(function() {
        $("input[name='mydata']").val(JSON.stringify(grid.getData()));
            });
}
```